# Display Count and All Blood Components

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to display the count of table entries with the same name.

I have a table like this

```
Blood Collection
--------------------
id   bloodComponent 
1    Whole Blood
2    Platelet
3    Plasma
4    Platelet
5    Plasma
6    Whole Blood
```

I would like the output to be something like:

```
Name         On Stock
------------------------
Whole Blood      2
Platelet         2
Plasma           2
```

I am using laravel as a framework...

Comment: SQL 101.... [`GROUP BY` and `COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html) - `SELECT \`bloodComponent\` as 'name', count(1) as 'On Stock' from \`bloodTable\` GROUP BY \`bloodComponent\``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
$bloodCollections = DB::table('blood_collections')
             ->select('bloodComponent as name', DB::raw('count(*) as onStock'))
             ->groupBy('bloodComponent')
             // Prepare $startDate & $endDate
             ->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate])
             ->get();
```

Then the loop:

```
foreach($bloodCollections as $collection) {
    // $collection['name'];
    // $collection['onStock'];
}
```

Comment: this works but how can i output the count? it does not display

Comment: In the query you have `DB::raw('count(*) as onStock` which will give you `onStock` as a field.

Comment: thank you sir this works pretty fine...i just want to add some...this is for my inventory report...i want to display a blood report from 2016-02-01 until 2016-02-21..how can i do this?

Comment: where did you get the created_at sir?

Comment: The `created_at` field is used by default in any table but if you have a different date field then use that field so for example, you may want to search a date field as `whereBetween('entry_date', [$start, $end])`.

Comment: all working fine...thank you so much sir..i greatly appreciate it

Comment: sir i've got another question...this works fine now.but what I want now is when the user clicks a button View Details it displays the name of the donors who donated whole blood... how can I store a route link into a variable so i can pass it on another page?

Comment: It's not clear. Please post question including your code/relationships and your attemots so far.

Comment: sir can you help me for this question...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557196/display-count-of-collected-and-released-blood-components?noredirect=1#comment58802398_35557196

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT bloodComponent, COUNT(*) AS tot 
    FROM tableName 
   GROUP BY Collection
```

in your result, you will have the names in `bloodComponent` key and the single total count in `tot` key