# Display Count of Collected and Released Blood Components

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to display the count of collected and released blood table entries with the same name.

I have a table like this

```
Blood Collection
--------------------------------------
id   BloodComponent      Remarks
1    Whole Blood         Collected
2    Platelet            Released
3    Plasma              Collected
4    Platelet            Released
5    Plasma              Collected
6    Whole Blood         Released
```

I would like the output to be something like:

```
Name         Collected       Released
---------------------------------------
Whole Blood      1              1
Platelet         0              2
Plasma           2              0
```

I am using laravel as a framework...

Comment: Can you share that which you have tried? My guess is that you're looking for a [crosstab query](http://evolt.org/node/26896/)

Comment: I have not tried any sir coz i got a hard time finding for the solution

Comment: Glad you've got the answer @JamesSachi :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In laravel:

```
$results = DB::table("BloodCollection")
  ->selectRaw("BloodComponent AS Name,SUM(IF(Remarks = 'Collected', 1, 0)) AS Collected,SUM(IF(Remarks = 'Released', 1, 0)) AS Released")
  ->groupBy("BloodComponent")
  ->get();
```

Or if you already have a `BloodCollection` model:

```
$results = BloodCollection::selectRaw("BloodComponent AS Name,SUM(IF(Remarks = 'Collected', 1, 0)) AS Collected,SUM(IF(Remarks = 'Released', 1, 0)) AS Released")
  ->groupBy("BloodComponent")
  ->get();
```

then:

```
foreach($results as $result){

    echo $results->Name . ": ".$results->Collected ." collected, ".$results->Released ." released.";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you require that rows become columns of data you would transform the rows using a crosstab query:

```
SELECT `BloodComponent` AS `Name`,
SUM(IF(`Remarks` = 'Collected', 1, 0)) AS `Collected`,
SUM(IF(`Remarks` = 'Released', 1, 0)) AS `Released`
FROM `BloodCollection`
GROUP BY `BloodComponent`
```

Here is an [informative post](http://evolt.org/node/26896/) showing the use of these kinds of queries in a more detailed fashion.

In Laravel:

```
DB::table("BloodCollection")
  ->selectRaw("`BloodComponent` AS `Name`,SUM(IF(`Remarks` = 'Collected', 1, 0)) AS `Collected`,SUM(IF(`Remarks` = 'Released', 1, 0)) AS `Released`")
  ->groupBy("BloodComponent")
  ->get();
```

Comment: can you do this in laravel query sir?

Comment: Then you need to go take a Laravel tutorial course. We're not here to write your code for you, we're here to teach you how to fish.

Comment: @JamesSachi if you have new questions you need to post the code and ask them. But, before you do that, please take a tutorial course.

Comment: @JamesSachi `foreach($data as $data)` Would you like to check that one